# Conditions when morphism saves convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

If $A_N\to A$ on $R$ in distribution, and $\xi :\ R\to S^1$, when is it true that $\xi(A_N)\to \xi(A)$?

Comment: If $\xi$ is a continuous function, then it will certainly preserve convergent sequences. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah thanks alot!